# Как правильно описать функцию, что бы в нее можно было передавать функцию, которая имеет пакет параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Существуют 2 функции

```
template <typename ... Argc>
void print(Argc ... argv)
{
   std::cout << sizeof...(argv) << " ";
}


template <class F, class ... Arrr>
void run(F f(Arrr...) )
{
    f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

При вызове

```
run(print);
```

gcc выводит такую ошибку

```
/home/eugeniy/CLionProjects/myfirsproject/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/eugeniy/CLionProjects/myfirsproject/main.cpp:782:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘run(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     run(print);
              ^
/home/eugeniy/CLionProjects/myfirsproject/main.cpp:571:6: note: candidate: template<class F, class ... Arrr> void run(F (*)(Arrr ...))
 void run(F f(Arrr...) )
      ^
/home/eugeniy/CLionProjects/myfirsproject/main.cpp:571:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/eugeniy/CLionProjects/myfirsproject/main.cpp:782:14: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘F’
     run(print);
              ^
```

Вопрос: Как мне надо объявить функцию run, что бы вызов run(print) работал корректно?

Comment: Никак, ни `run`, ни `print` не являются функциями. Это два шаблона функций, поэтому что-то одно для начала нужно явно инстанциировать.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то похожее можно сделать, если `print` будет функциональным объектом.

```
#include <iostream>

struct print_t {
  template <typename ... Argc>
  void operator()(Argc ... argv) {
     std::cout << sizeof...(argv) << " ";
  }
};
constexpr print_t print;

template<class F>
void run(F f) {
    f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}

int main() {
  run(print);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Никак.

При передаче адреса шаблона функции в другую функцию в качестве параметра **нужно** знать, какая именно её реализация будет использована. То есть на этапе компиляции нужно выяснить, `run` принимает `void(*)(int)` или `void(*)(float, Foo)`. Вывести подобную информацию, анализируя код функции `run`, компилятор не может, так как это не поддерживается стандартом языка.

Другое дело - использовать абсолютно логичный вариант @Abyx, который позволяет передать `объект некоторого класса` в `run`, тип которого будет известен во время компиляции, а уже внутри `run` будет вызвана одна из реализаций шаблонного оператора `operator()(Args...)`.

Чтобы не писать для всех шаблонных функций много кода, а использовать `run` напрямую (почти), можно сделать следующим образом:

```
#define pass(func) [](auto&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)) { return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

и использовать `run` так:

```
template <class F>
void run(F f)
{
    f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}

int main() {
    run(pass(print));
}
```